Page 13 of Weibel's Intro to Hom. Alg. - How do we get from one diagram to the other (question in the SES to Long Exact Sequence proof)
The goal theorem the book is trying to explain is:
Theorem 1.3.1. Let $0\to A_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{f} B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{g} C_{\bullet} \to 0$ be a short exact sequence (SES) of chain complexes.  Then there are natural maps $\partial:H_n(C) \to H_{n-1}(A)$, called connecting homomorphisms, such that
$$
\cdots \xrightarrow{g} H_{n+1}(C) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_n(A) \xrightarrow{f} H_n(B) \xrightarrow{g} H_{n}(C) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_{n-1}(A) \xrightarrow{f} \cdots
$$
is an exact sequence.  That is on page 10 and a few pages away begins the proof.

Namely they take one arrow $A_n \xrightarrow{d} A_{n-1}$ respectively for each complex $A,B,C$ and connect them all according to the SES of complexes, they then add in the kernels and cokernels in the same way as the Snake Lemma proceeds.  This diagram is commutative and you can prove so in a diagram chase, and the rows are each exact.  It then says, "we see that the rows are exact in the commutative diagram", and then displays a perfect Snake starting diagram except the $n$th degree cokernels are in the top row and the $(n-1)$th degree kernels are in bottom row.  They are connected by vertical $d$ arrows as in the first (expanded) Snake Lemma diagram.  I am not sure whether this $d$ is related to the $d$ in the first diagram.
Question. How do you get to the second diagram from the first diagram?
I am comfortable with applying the Snake Lemma and hopefully the "pasting" on the next page in order to complete the full proof.  So, I just need help with this one step.

The $d$ maps in the second diagram are induced by those in the first. If you start with $d: A_n \to A_{n-1}$, since $d\circ d =0$, its image lies in $Z_{n-1}A$: we get a map $d: A_n \to Z_{n-1}A$. Now again since  $d\circ d =0$, we see that $d$ sends everything in $dA_{n+1}$ to zero, so $d$ induces a map $A_n/dA_{n+1} \to Z_{n-1}A$. This is where each vertical map in the second diagram comes from.

Well, the two rows in the second diagram appear in the first diagram (the first row is the fourth row in the first diagram with $n$ replaced by $n-1$, and the second row is the first row in the first diagram with $n-1$ replaced by $n$). If you cannot see why the first and fourth rows of the first diagram are exact, I can help you with that too. The first diagram is only used to justify the exactness of rows. Commutativity with the $d$ maps (same as the chain complex maps) is straightforward.
Hope this helps. :)

What I'm not seeing is how the $d$ map gets inserted into the second diagram there.  I know that the rows of kernels and cokernels (in both diagrams) are exact.

@DanielDonnelly: Oh okay. As the other answer points out, that is just factoring the map $d\colon A_n\to A_{n-1}$.
